# How do I correctly get my entity plus all of its events from the repository / store?

Tags: cqrs, event-sourcing

So I learned from a blogpost about CQRS that you don't ever let your entities be created out of thin air. Instead, you let them be created by another aggregate / entity.

So for example, the `UserRegistered` event is not associated with the id of the user that was just registered, but with the id of the entity that registered the new user (e.g. `Visitor`), is that correct?

If I'm correct then I run into a problem. What if I now want to perform a new action on the user. I learned from blog posts that you should retrieve the user entity from a repository by the id (which basically is an empty entity at that point), and you get the history of events from the event-store using the same id, and then you execute that history of events on that entity to bring it up to date, and then you try to perform the new action.

But that very first event, the event that created the user entity in the first place, wasn't saved with the id of the user, so I don't get that event back. I could only get that event back by finding out which other entity created the user and then I need to perform that action on that entity first. But I see no way of finding out which entity created the user. So I assume I just have a misunderstanding about the system. So what am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

> So I learned from a blogpost about CQRS that you don't ever let your entities be created out of thin air. Instead, you let them be created by another aggregate / entity.

That's not specific to CQRS -- it's a general observation about modeling a domain correctly.  Reference: Udi Dahan [Don't Create Aggregate Roots](http://udidahan.com/2009/06/29/dont-create-aggregate-roots/).

> So for example, the UserRegistered event is not associated with the id of the user that was just registered, but with the id of the entity that registered the new user (e.g. Visitor), is that correct?

No.  It is more correct to say that the UserRegistered event should be associated with the identities of both entities.

> So what am I missing?

[ddd](/questions/tagged/ddd)

Event Sourcing does use the term `repository`, but that term is borrowed from domain driven design.  You can read up on aggregates, and aggregate roots, but for your specific conflict the answer is that in an event sourced world, the repository loads a history, and builds an entity from that history.  The history needs to include all events needed to build that history.

If in your model, `User` and `Visitor` are transactionally isolated concepts, and you have `UserRegistered` event that references both of them, the event needs to be saved in the history of the object that changed.

Even though that history didn't exist until the user was registered.  *Creation patterns are weird.*

> So you're saying that the event should be saved in the history of the user? As the first event?

Yes, exactly.

> I mean, the apply(UserCreatedEvent) method is usually on the user-object right? But you can only call it after you've instantiated it.

Review what Greg Young has to say about [Functional Domain Models](https://goodenoughsoftware.net/2012/10/01/functional-domain-models-and-event-sourcing/).  But the basic idea is that you are doing a left fold

```
state[n+1] = state[n].apply(event)
```

And your question essentially winds this back to "what caused the first cause?"

```
State currentState = ...?

events.each ( e -> currentState = currentState.apply(e) )
```

For newly created objects, my suggestion is that you start the lifetime of all objects from a common *SEED* state.  But you just as easily have the first event in the history be passed to a constructor instead of applying it to a seed.

> how do you rerun that first event, which created the entity. Because if the apply() method is a method on the entity, then you can only apply the EntityCreatedEvent after you've instantiated the entity.  You see why I get stuck there?

Yes -- you are confusing the Entity with the Entity's *state*.

```
class Bob implements Entity<Bob> {
    class State implements Value<Seed> {

        State apply(Event e) {...}

        static State SEED = new State(...);

        // ...
    }

    class Factory implements Factory<Bob> {
        Bob rebuild(Iterable<Event> history) {
            return rebuild(State.SEED, history);    
        } 

        Bob rebuild(State currentState, Iterable<Event> history) {
            for(Event e : history) {
                currentState = currentState.apply(e);
            }

            return create(currentState);
        }

        Bob rebuild(State currentState) {
            return new Bob(currentState);
        }
    }
}
```

That's the long form spelling of what's going on.  This simpler version is also "fine".

```
Bob rebuild(Iterable<Event> history) {
    Bob target = new Bob();

    for(Event e : history) {
        target.apply(e);
    }
    return target;   
}
```

Or even

```
Bob rebuild(Iterable<Event> history) {
    return new Bob(history);   
}
```

One possibility is that you are confused about where the `UserRegistered` event comes from -- since it describes a change to the state of `User`, rather than `Visitor`, it should be considered part of the `User` module.

Most commands, you read from a repository, makes some changes, and then store the result in the same repository.  But creation is *weird*; you read state from `VisitorRepository`, but write state to `UserRepository` -- because the `Visitor` didn't change.

Comment: So you're saying that the event should be saved in the history of the user? As the first event? But then how do you apply that event when you rerun history? I mean, the `apply(UserCreatedEvent)` method is usually on the user-object right? But you can only call it after you've instantiated it. Or do you make the apply() method a static method? So you can use it without / before instantiating a user?

Comment: I think you misunderstand me a bit. Your answer has to do with the state of the entire application. But I'm just talking about the state of one entity, isolated. I learned that to bring an entity up to date, you don't have rerun all the events of the entire application. Instead you can just rerun all the events for that one entity. And then I wonder, how do you rerun that first event, which created the entity. Because if the `apply()` method is a method on the entity, then you can only apply the `EntityCreatedEvent` after you've instantiated the entity. You see why I get stuck there?

Answer (score 0):

I create an open source project where I have some practical examples of how event sourcing works in practice to create events and rehydrate the model. Take a look, maybe it might help you out to understand a little bit better the concept.

https://github.com/politrons/Scalaydrated